# jQuery chosen cannot add value with slash character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Chosen multiselect, which I populate with options to chose:

`CRP0/Vanilla Testing, CRP1 Testing,  CRP2 Testing`

And the options are populated properly. I can choose any of those and if I submit, all the values are saved properly.

[image]

The problem starts when I want to edit the object. When I open edit screen, in which there should be my multiselect with previously chosen values, it only populates selected values that does not have special chars like "\".

[image]

Values are taken from the DB properly.
Any ideas how to solve this problem without blocking the possibility to use special characters for the end user?

Comment: I would be much more helpful if you could create a working example of the problem for us.

Comment: 1. I create an object in which I can choose from multiselect some values
2. I save it and all the chosen values are properly saved
3. I want to edit it and when I open edit screen only values without special characters are in the multiselect as chosen